# How can we compute $\int_{0}^{\pi}{-\frac{2\cos^2(x)}{(1+t\cos(x))^3}}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I tried to compute the following integral but it got really messy .. ( we have $|t| < 1$)

$$\int_{0}^{\pi}{-\frac{2\cos^2(x)}{(1+t\cos(x))^3}}dx$$

I tried integration by parts, substitution. There is maybe a trick I don't see. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you integrating with respect to $x$ or with respect to $t$?

Comment: Hint:  Let $\displaystyle I(t) = \int_0^{\pi} \frac{1}{1 + t \cos (x) } dx$. The required integral is $-\dfrac{d^2}{dt^2} I(t)$.

Comment: One way forward is to exploit the evenness of the integrand and then use contour integration on the unit circle of the complex plane.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the most important yes it's $dx$

Comment: @MarkViola I don't think so. If $f(t) = \dfrac{1}{1 + t \cos(x)}$, then $f'(t) = -\dfrac{\cos (x)}{(1 + t \cos(x))^2}$ and $f '' (t) =  \dfrac{2\cos^2 (x)}{(1 + t \cos(x))^3}$. I hope I haven't messed up the differentiation.

Comment: if $ f(x,t) = \frac{cos(x)}{(1+tcos(x))^2} $ then $f_t(x,t) = -\frac{2cos^2(x)}{(1+tcos(x))^3} $

Comment: @sudeep5221 I missed the $-2$ in the numerator of the original integral.  I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, try:
$$I(t)=\int_0^\pi\frac{1}{1+t\cos(x)}dx$$
notice that:
$$I'(t)=-\int_0^\pi\frac{\cos(x)}{\left[1+t\cos(x)\right]^2}dx$$
$$I''(t)=\int_0^\pi\frac{2\cos^2(x)}{\left[1+t\cos(x)\right]^3}dx$$
so you just want: $-I''(t)$

---

$$I(t)=\int_0^\pi\frac{1}{1+t\cos(x)}dx$$
now if we use the substitution $u=\tan(x/2)\Rightarrow dx=\frac{2}{1+u^2}du,\cos(x)=\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}$ and we will have the bounds $(0,\infty)$:
$$I(t)=\int_0^\infty\frac{2}{1+t\frac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}}\frac{du}{1+u^2}=\int_0^\infty\frac{2du}{(1+u^2)+t(1-u^2)}=\int_0^\infty\frac{2du}{(1-t)u^2+(1+t)}$$
now I think you can take it from here

---

We can rewrite this as:
$$I(t)=\frac{2}{1+t}\int_0^\infty\frac{du}{\frac{1-t}{1+t}u^2+1}$$
now if we make the substitution: $\sqrt{\frac{1-t}{1+t}}u=\tan v$ we will get:
$$I(t)=\frac{2}{1+t}\sqrt{\frac{1+t}{1-t}}\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sec^2v dv}{\tan^2v+1}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$$
Which finally will give us:
$$\mathbb{I}(t)=-I''(t)=-\frac{2\pi t^2+\pi}{(1-t^2)^{5/2}}$$